# Event object in Google apps using changeType

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am making and app that sends emails to different people accordingly to a google sheet. Now I am struggling with the automatization of the process.

What I want to do is create a trigger that sends the email after a new row is added to the sheet and I know it could be done using an event object.

Could you guys help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want it to trigger when a user adds a row?. Or makes an edit?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Hi Cooper, I want to trigger when a user adds a row.

Comment: Okay then the script below should work.  You just have to create an installable trigger from the script editor Edit/Current Project Triggers menu

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sort of script if the change is a user inserting a row into a given sheet.

```
function onAChange(e) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.changeType=="INSERT_ROW" && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Your Sheet Name") {
    sendEmail()
  }
}
```

The event object looks like this:

```
{"authMode":"","changeType":"INSERT_ROW","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}
```

[on Change Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)